# how to extract part of url server side in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express

Currently working on a nodejs express server. And I think I'm doing something in an inefficient way. I have this route set up

```
 app.get('/admin/scanTable/:table', require('./AUTH/ValidateCookie.js'), require('./AUTH/verifyURI.js'), require('./ROUTES/render.js'));
```

so the url here is /admin/scanTable/:table. I know I can get the whole path with req.route.path. I know I can use req.params.table to collect the table parameter. But the thing I don't know how to get is the first part of the path, in this case **admin**. I know I could get it by looking for / symbols and slicing the parts I need from req.route.path but I figure with all these functionalities that express has, there's probably a better way of doing this. 
I know I can use

```
app.use('/admin', function(req, res, next){console.log('admin called'), next();});
```

to check if this part of the uri was called to then execute some code, but it's not really what I want. Can anyone tell me the easiest way to find this? At the moment I have attached a variable to req.string whenever `app.use('/admin'` is called it will attach the string admin to this variable which then makes it available to all other functions that are called. But even this feels like overkill. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options you describe are valid and straightforward:

- Using a regex on `req.route.path`, a la `/^admin/.test(req.route.path)`
- Using middleware to attach a new property to the req object, a la

  ```
  app.use('/admin', function(req, res, next){ req.adminRoute = true; next();});
  ```

  or if you need to do this same thing for all admin routes, do it once:

  ```
  var adminRouter = require("express").Router();
  router.get("/scanTable/:table", require("./AUTH/ValidateCookie.js"), ...);
  router.use(function (req, res, next) { req.adminRoute = true; next(); }));
  app.use("/admin", adminRouter);
  ```

I don't know the context of your application, but I would consider using the last example, and putting anything else that's specific to /admin routes as middleware also.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply; I'm always worrying about straying from the path of righteous server-tinkering ^^